# Not able to reorder columns (fct_reorder())

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I am trying to reorder columns to get a descending column formation. The plot that I have so far is attached below:

[image]

Ideally the plot should look like this, but still be filled with the the expert levels.

[image]

This is the R code I have so far:

```
# !!!
survey_data_barchart %>%
    dplyr::filter(!is.na(expert.level)) %>% 
    dplyr::filter(!is.na(country)) %>% 
    group_by(expert.level) %>% 
    count(country) %>%
    # mutate(country = fct_reorder(country, n)) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = reorder(country, +n), n, fill = expert.level)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    coord_flip() +
    theme(legend.position="top",
          axis.text.x = element_text(size = 20, vjust = 1.3),
          axis.text.y = element_text(size = 15),
          legend.title = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          # axis.title.y = element_blank(),
          # axis.title.x = element_blank(),
          rect = element_blank(),
          legend.text = element_text(size=25),
          axis.title.x = element_text(size=20, vjust = 0.5)) +
    guides(fill = guide_legend("")) +
    labs(x = "",
         y = "Responses") +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2")
    #scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2))
```

Data that is going to the ggplot expression looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 104 × 3
# Groups:   expert.level [5]
   expert.level           country         n
   <chr>                  <chr>       <int>
 1 Anaesthesia technician Belgium         2
 2 Anaesthesia technician Greece          1
 3 Anaesthesia technician Moldova         1
 4 Anaesthesia technician Romania         2
 5 Anaesthesia technician Russia          3
 6 Anaesthesia technician Switzerland     1
 7 Consultant             Albania         3
 8 Consultant             Austria        24
 9 Consultant             B&H             4
10 Consultant             Belarus         1
```

Thank you for your help and wish you a nice weekend!

Grigorij

Comment: If you look at `?reorder`, it orders data by the `mean` by default. You want to reorder by the sum, so pass `FUN = sum` as an argument to `reorder`. If you switch to `fct_reorder` as in your title, the name of the argument is `.fun`.

Comment: Amazing!!! Thank you Gregor!